# Aggregating Hierarchies with SCOPE MDX

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, mdx, aggregation

I have have a requirement in SSAS cube to apply different set of calculations at different levels in hierarchy and also at the ALL member level of each of the hierarchy level. I am using Scope assignment and successful in doing it at Leaf level but the All level I can't scope on since there is a hierarchy with 4 levels and each level has separate rule in addition to the the ALL levels for each of the four. The reason why I don't scope on all is clarified in this post http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2009/11/scope-problems-with-mdx-calculated-members

My scope statement looks like this

```
SCOPE(DESCENDANTS([Commodity].[Category],,AFTER));
THIS = /*Calculation logic*/                   
END SCOPE;


SCOPE(DESCENDANTS([Commodity].[SubCategory],,AFTER));
THIS = /*Calculation logic*/                   
END SCOPE;

SCOPE(DESCENDANTS([Commodity].[Product],,AFTER));
THIS = /*Calculation logic*/                   
END SCOPE;
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old post but I was trying so solve this too.
FREEZE; seems to do the trick

Comment: well, I have a few queries running extremely slow now so I need to find an other way